# Error al obtener datos json al publicar sitio web

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual me devuelve un json para llenar una tabla HTML, y funciona bien localmente, el problema es que al publicar mi sitio web me arroja un error.

Aqui lleno un dropdownlist desde el controller para filtrar mi tabla

```html
<div style="float: left;margin:0 0 0 10px;">
@Html.DropDownList("agente", new SelectList(ViewBag.List_Agente, "Id", "Nombre"), new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm" })
</div>
<div style="float: right;">
    <input type="button" value="Buscar" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-lg" name="search" id="search" />
</div>
```

```html
<script src="~/js/Jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        datos();       
    });  
   
 $(document).on('click', '#search', function (event)
{
    datos();
});


//aqui se captura un ID de acuerdo a un valor seleccionado en un dropdownlist
$('#agente').change(function () {
    agente = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
});

  function datos() {
        $.getJSON("/Indicadores/CurvaList?agente=" + agente, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (idx, opt) {
                $('#Datos').append('<tr><td>' + opt.Codigo + '</td><td>' + opt.Nombre + '</td><td>' + opt.Pronostico + '</td><td>' + '' + '</td><td>' + opt.PronosticoAA + '</td><td>' + opt.Entregado + '</td><td>' + opt.DiferenciaAA + '</td><td>' + '' + '</td><td>' + opt.PronosticoSA + '</td><td>' + opt.EntregadoSA + '</td><td>' + opt.DiferenciaSA + '</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="cod_A" id="cod_A" value="A" /></td></tr>');
            });
        }, 'json');
    }       
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi controlador

```html
 public JsonResult CurvaList(int agente = 0)
 {
   List<ClassCurva> curva = new List<ClassCurva>();
    if (agente != 0)
    {
     curva = bd.Database.SqlQuery<ClassCurva>("select...").ToList();
    }
return Json(curva, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult Activos_Curva(int agente = 0)
{
  if (Session["Nombre"] != null)
  {
  ViewData["Nombre"] = Session["Nombre"].ToString();
  List<MyTable> lst_Agentes = new List<MyTable>();
  lst_Agentes = bd.MyTable.Where(x => x.Activo == true).OrderBy(i => i.Id).ToList();
   ViewBag.List_Agente = lst_Agentes;
   
   CurvaList(agente);
   }
   else
   {
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
   }
return View();
}
```

Comment: Fíjate en la URL de tu sitio si este no está publicado en una subruta (algo común en IIS cuando se trabaja con varios sitios), algo del tipo `http://miweb.mx/misitio/...`

Comment: Hola tienes razon @Vlady como solucionaria eso? ya revise mis demas páginas y es el mismo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu vista agrega una variable javascript global con código MVC de C#, puedes ponerlo en un layout o directamente en tu html:

```
<script>var siteURL = "@Url.Content("~")/";</script>
```

Ya en tus llamadas Ajax usas esa variable:

```
$.getJSON(siteURL + "Indicadores/CurvaList?agente=" + agente, function (data) { ...
```

Así tus llamadas Ajax funcionan cuando corres tu sitio desde Visual Studio como también cuando lo vayas a publicar en IIS.

Comment: Pero  dentro de  "@Url.Content("~")/" tendria que poner www.mysite.mx? o como seria?

Comment: No, ya no necesitas especificar la URL de tu sitio, `Url.Content("~")` te devuelve la ruta en la que está publicado

Comment: Funciono, muchas gracias he aprendido algo nuevo